# Why is this not thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Why is this not thread-safe?
From my understanding, the result should be a string of `100`s.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int*> values(100, new int(0));
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::vector<std::mutex> mutexes(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        threads.emplace_back([](int* v, std::mutex* m)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(*m);
                (*v)++;
            }
        }, values[i], &mutexes[i]);
    }
    for (auto& t : threads) t.join();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutexes[i]);
        std::cout << (*(values[i])) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863 9863
```

Comment: Your values vector is wrong. This constructor for std::vector causes all elements to point to the same int, as a result your code will print a series of 1000s if you fix the locking. Otherwise if you fix the value vector, then the code is still thread safe without locks.

Comment: no need to use a vector of pointers at all: https://godbolt.org/z/oMsWx4

Answer (score 0):

You need just a single mutex. With 100 mutexes each thread will immediately lock its own mutex instead of waiting for other threads so no sync happens.

Comment: Also note that you create just a single `int` value - vector contains 100 equal pointers to it - and the allocated memory leaks.